# Why won't MariaDB accept my string variable as table name on my sql query?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, xampp, mariadb, vb.net-2010

I'm having problems with retrieving data data from my xampp database. I'm pretty new to this so i have no idea how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
Dim contract As String

Private Sub projectchart()
  OpenConnection()
  sql = "SELECT activityname, progress FROM '" & contract & "';"
  dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
  Chart2.Series("Progress").Points.Clear()

  While dr.Read
    Chart2.Series("Progress").Points.AddXY(dr("activityname"),dr("progress"))
  End While

  cmd.Dispose()
  con.Close()
End Sub
```

When I run this code this error comes out

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near "c00101" at line 1*

c00101 is the table name and is what the variable contract holds

But when I try to run the code in the format below, everything runs okay, the chart I'm trying to display data with works perfectly.

```
sql = "SELECT activityname, progress FROM c00101;"
```

I really have no clue why this happens. Can any help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd looked at the actual SQL, rather than the code that builds it, you'd have seen the difference, i.e. the single quotes.  That's for specifying text values.  Just as you put double quotes around literal `Strings` in VB but not around variables or other identifiers, so you put single quotes around text literals in SQL but around identifiers.

Comment: * *not* around identifiers? Or backticks can be used to [quote identifiers in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

Comment: @AndrewMorton, yes, graves (as is their correct name) are used to escape identifiers in MySQL, just as brackets are used in Microsoft flavours of SQL and, in fact, in VB as well.  Whether in SQL or in VB, such is generally done when the identifier is a reserved word or contains special characters and would not otherwise be interpreted as an identifier.  Clearly, there's no issue with this table name so no need for escaping.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding your answer. Can you please explain further?

Comment: I actually figured it out just now. Thanks for pointing out the proper usage of single quotes.

Comment: @jmcilhinney According to wiktionar it is grave accent the plural being grave accents. Apparently pronounced like what we visit at the cemetery. I think an alternate pronunciation is gra-ve with a short a or schwa a in the first syllable.

Comment: @Mary, I learned French in school and it is used much in that language, with the accent going the other way being an acute.  The pronunciation that I've always used is basically like the word "carve".

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks! That is what I wanted to know. If I have a pronunciation in my head I can remember much better.